# disabling extra message after changing to new directory

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Whenever directory is changed, it is displaying the new directory name:

```
# cd /home/
Directory: /home/
# cd ~
Directory: /root
```

How to disable it?

We are logging into csh. We already verified /etc/csh.cshrc, /etc/profile, /etc/csh.login.

Answer (score 1):

try looking in the user folder instead of only looking for the system wide files.

if you are logged in as root:

```
/root/.cshrc
```

or

```
/home/[USERNAME]/.cshrc
```

i do not know for additional csh files similiar to bash files (.bash_login .bash_logout) in the user folder, so you might need to check the existence with ls -a for showing the "hidden" . files.